# Cómo puedo pasar la variable de un for() en PHP A Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bucle-for

necesito recibir una variable en Javascript desde un for() en PHP, para un form.

Y  mi objetivo es cambiar las opciones de un segundo select dependiendo de la option_seleccionada del primer select.

El detalle está en que los select están numerados con un for($n=1; $n<$num_var; $n++);

Y el select_1 afecta al segundo_select_1

Y el select_2 afecta al segundo_select_2

Tengo lo siguiente: (Sí Funciona)

```
<script>            
                    
function myFunction(){
var x=document.nombre_de_form.select_1.value;
if(x=="option_seleccionada"){
document.getElementById('segundo_select_1').innerHTML="<option> ... </option>";
}
}
</script>
```

Y con PHP de la siguiente forma: (Sí Funciona)

```
<script>            
                    
function myFunction(){
var x=document.nombre_de_form.select_<?php echo 1; ?>.value;
if(x=="option_seleccionada"){
document.getElementById('segundo_select_<?php echo 1; ?>').innerHTML="<option> ... </option>";
}
}
</script>
```

Pero necesito recibir la variable del for() de la siguiente forma: (NO Funciona)

```
<script>            
                    
function myFunction(){
var x=document.nombre_de_form.select_<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>.value;
if(x=="option_seleccionada"){
document.getElementById('segundo_select_<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>').innerHTML="<option> ... </option>";
}
}
</script>
```

En resumen `<?php echo 1; ?>` sí funciona; pero no funcionan `<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>` ni `<?php echo $n; ?>`.

...
...
Sí ya he probado varias comibaciones con comillas simples y dobles, incluso ya probé terminar el `</script>` luego empezar y terminar `<php>` y luego volver a iniciar `<script>.`

La variable sí funciona así:

```
var varphp=<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>;
      alert(varphp);
```

Lo de la función si creo que también la voy a tener que numerar con el mismo for().

...
El código lo tengo así: index.php

```
<html>
<form> //empiezo el form
<form>  //elementos del form
<?php  ?> //abro y cierro PHP para el for
<form>  //elementos del form
<script> </script> //abro y cierro myFunction
<?php  ?> //abro y cierro PHP para terminar for
</form> // termino el form
<html>
```

...

...
Listo ya quedó y ya se cual es el problema. Gracias a masterguru que detectó el problema de la función repetida pero yo creía que lo tenía controlado porque ya había funcionado de una forma que no debío funcionar y de ahí partí para tratar de solucionarlo.

La función yo la estaba llamando desde afuera del for() según para evitar problemas adicionales pero salio contraproducente. Entonces ya la puse dentro del for() como debía estar desde el principio y problema resuelto.

Comment: Probaste usando comillas dobles?

Comment: No acabo de entender donde tienes ese cacho de código de javascript. Piensa que si lo tienes en un bucle **for** de PHP vas a repetir el mismo nombre de función todo el rato, y es probable que sólo uno de ellos te funcione, pero no el resto porque tendras duplicados los nombres de la función.

Comment: ¿Probaste imprimiendo directamente `$n`? Es decir `<?php echo $n; ?>`

Comment: diria que te has liado con tu última adición de código y has confundido `<form>` con bucles **for**... Si no es así ojo con eso pues no puedes anidar elementos `<form>` de ese modo y esperar que funcionen

Comment: Las comillas exactamente donde? ..... Algún otra alternativa a json_encode ?

Comment: No estan anidado el form; es un solo form; simplemente lo que ago es abrir y cerrar PHP antes y despues de los elementos del form para no tener que escribir el codigo HTML dentro de PHP.

Comment: No se de que comillas me hablas, lo siento (si es que me lo dices a mi)... y el problema no creo que sea el json_encode, que dices que te da bien el valor, sino que repites el script continuamente y por tanto la función con el mismo nombre

Comment: Lo de las comillas es para el primer comentario de Julio. ....  
Ok ya intenté numerar también myFunction1() para evitar ese conflicto pero ya no me esta funcionando. Creo que voy a tener que replantear el método para hacer lo del form.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado Gracias a masterguru que detectó el bucle en myFunction.

```
<script>            
                    
function myFunction<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>(){
var x=document.nombre_de_form.select_<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>.value;
if(x=="option_seleccionada"){
document.getElementById('segundo_select_<?php echo json_encode($n); ?>').innerHTML="<option> ... </option>";
}
}
</script>
```